# using a function to print basic student information in c++

Tags: c++

I want to print in c++ some general information about students by using a function with parameters

```
void generalities(string fname,string lname,string email,int phone, int age) {\
cout << fname << lname<<" email: "<<email << " Phone: "<<phone<< " Age "<<age;\
}
int main() {\
std::cout << "Team generalities";\
generalities("Ledjet","Lushka","ledjet.lushka@cit.edu.al",0694339874,20);
generalities("Enio","Sefa","enio.sefa@cit.edu.al",0699274494,20);
  
return 0;
}
```

but I get the following errors

> error: invalid digit "9" in octal constant 
> error: variable or field ‘generalities’ declared void
> error: ‘string’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘std::string’?
> error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
> error: ‘generalities’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: Fyi literal integers with leading `0` are considered *octal* (base8).; not decimal (base10). Therefore only digits 0..7 are considered valid. Either lose the leading `0`'s or use strings (which you should be doing anyway if these really are phone numbers).

Comment: Don't use integers for things like phone or credit card numbers. As noted, they can't properly handle leading zeros, and there are also other problems with them in those contexts. Use strings instead.

Comment: Has someone told you to put backslashes at the end of every line? Ignore what they say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer @digito_evo gave was a nice improvement. I would go further and overload the operator<< for the struct.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


struct Generalities
{
    std::string fname;
    std::string lname;
    std::string email;
    std::string phone;
    std::string age;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Generalities& g);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Generalities& g)
{
    os << g.fname << ' ' << g.lname << " email: " << g.email << " Phone: "<< g.phone << " Age: " << g.age << '\n';
    return os;
}

int main( )
{
    std::cout << "Team generalities\n";
    std::cout << Generalities{ "Ledjet", "Lushka", "ledjet.lushka@cit.edu.al", "0694339874", "20" };
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Because **0** at the beginning of an integer literal means that it should be interpreted as an **octal** value. Now you don't want that. So convert `phone` and `age` to `std::string`.

Also, Use a `struct` to make the work easier (instead of many many parameters):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


struct Generalities
{
    std::string fname { std::string( "Unknown" ) }; // use in-class initializers
    std::string lname { std::string( "Unknown" ) }; // to prevent any problems
    std::string email { std::string( "Unknown" ) }; // in case default initialization
    std::string phone { std::string( "Unknown" ) }; // happens
    std::string age   { std::string( "Unknown" ) };
};

void printGeneralities( const Generalities& generalities )
{
    std::cout << "First Name: " << generalities.fname << " --- Last Name: " << generalities.lname
              << " --- Email: " << generalities.email << " --- Phone: " << generalities.phone
              << " --- Age: " << generalities.age << '\n';
}

int main( )
{
    std::cout << "Team generalities\n";

    printGeneralities( { "Ledjet", "Lushka", "ledjet.lushka@cit.edu.al", "0694339874", "20" } );
    printGeneralities( { "Enio", "Sefa", "enio.sefa@cit.edu.al", "0699274494", "20" } );

    Generalities generalities; // empty, i.e. non of the members have real values
    printGeneralities( generalities );
}
```

**Output:**

```
Team generalities
First Name: Ledjet --- Last Name: Lushka --- Email: ledjet.lushka@cit.edu.al --- Phone: 0694339874 --- Age: 20
First Name: Enio --- Last Name: Sefa --- Email: enio.sefa@cit.edu.al --- Phone: 0699274494 --- Age: 20
First Name: Unknown --- Last Name: Unknown --- Email: Unknown --- Phone: Unknown --- Age: Unknown
```

Comment: if you think that overloading operator<< makes the code cleaner, please add it and I will delete my answer(It will be better to have one good and complete answer)

Comment: @Heto Yes, that's a better way. But no, don't delete your answer. You've already got an upvote.